# scroll is not coming in mobile view and because of that content size is tiny to see

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Scroll is not coming when I am switching to mobile view in chrome developer tool, all the content are visible in screen which is making very hard to read as they became very tiny to for the height adjustment.
So contents are getting adjusted and hence it is getting tiny.
   Scroll is not coming when I am switching to mobile view in chrome developer tool, all the content are visible in screen which is making very hard to read as they became very tiny to for the height adjustment.
So contents are getting adjusted and hence it is getting tiny.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GetToWork</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    .main-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        align-items: center;
        font-family:Lato, Arial, Sans serif;
        padding: 0 10%;
    }
    body {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    footer {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url(./Group\ 4265.svg);
    }
    .header-icon{
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .margin-top-60 {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .lato-bold {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1.21;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .lato-bolder {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .font-size-21 {
        font-size: 21px;
    }
    .font-size-18 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .margin-top-20 {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .margin-top-30 {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .margin-bottom-30 {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .width-100-percent {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-around{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-between{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-between{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .flex{
        display: flex;
    }
    .justify-flex-end {
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .maroon-bg {
        color:#7a2693;
    }
    .width-80-percent {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .dashed-border{
        border: 1px dashed #8b4c9e;
        width: 320px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: super;
    }
    .padding-left-right-10-percent {
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    .width-150 {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .margin-bottom-20{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .flex-column {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .footerIcons {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
    }
    .margin-left-20 {
        margin-left:20px;
    }
    .color-white{
        color: white;
    }
    /* @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .main-container {
            padding: 0;
        } 
       
    } */

  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="header-icon"><img src="./Group 4254.svg" class="width-100"></div>
        <div class="lato-bold">Package Purchase Successful!</div>
        <div class="font-size-21 margin-top-60">Hi <span class="lato-bolder" th:text="${invoiceName}"></span></div>
        <div class="font-size-18 margin-top-20">You have successfully purchased the <span class="lato-bolder" th:text="${planName}">SUPERSAVER</span> package.</div>
        <div class="font-size-18"> Package details can be found below.</div>
        <div class="margin-top-20 font-size-18 lato-bolder">Simplify Office Commute with GetToWork.</div>
        <div class="font-size-18 lato-bolder">Enjoy Stress-free work days. </div>
        <hr class="margin-top-30 width-100-percent">
        <section id="packageDetails" class="width-80-percent margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30">
            <div class="flex-justify-space-around font-size-18">
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Package Name</span>
                    <span th:text="${planName}" class="margin-top-30">SUPERSAVER</span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Rides/Validity</span>
                    <div class="margin-top-30">
                        <span th:text="${planBooking}">10 Rides/</span>
                        <span th:text="${planDays}">90 Days</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Cost</span>
                    <div class="margin-top-30">&#x20b9;<span th:text="${invoicePrice}">200</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="flex-justify-space-around font-size-18 margin-top-30">
                    <span th:text="${planName}">SuperSaver</span>
                    <div>
                    <span th:text="${planBooking}">10 Rides/</span>
                    <span th:text="${planDays}">90 Days</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>&#x20b9; <span th:text="${invoicePrice}">200</div>
            </div> -->

        </section>
        <hr class="width-100-percent"> 
        <section>
            <div class="margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30">
                <img src="./Shape.svg">
                <span class="dashed-border"></span>
                <img src="./Group 2224.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="margin-bottom-20 flex-justify-space-between lato-bolder">
                <span>Home</span>
                <!-- <span class="visibilty-hide"></span> -->
                <span>Office</span>
            </div>
            <div class="margin-bottom-30 flex-justify-space-between">
                <span class="width-150">Infosys Pvt Ltd, Electronic City, Bangalore </span>
                <!-- <span class="visibilty-hide"></span> -->
                <span class="width-150 justify-flex-end flex">MoveInsync , 17th Cross, HSR Laypot, Bangalore</span>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
      
    <footer>
        <div class="footerIcons">
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between">
                <a class="color-white" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/14637641/admin/">
                    <img src="./Group 3013.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/GetToWork6">
                    <img src="./Group 3012.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/Get_To_Work_MIS/">
                    <img src="./Group 3015.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Get-To-Work-1391007324386201/">
                    <img src="./Path 611.svg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between margin-top-20">
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="color-white">Copyright © MoveinSync Technology Solutions Pvt Ltd</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <a class="color-white" target="_blank" href="http://gettowork.io">
                    gettowork.io
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20"  href="">
                    Privacy Policy
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" href="">
                    Terms and Conditions
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" href="">
                    Help & FAQs
                </a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page doesn't fit in mobile screen because the `viewport` meta is missing.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Here is your page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GetToWork</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    .main-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        align-items: center;
        font-family:Lato, Arial, Sans serif;
        padding: 0 10%;
    }
    body {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    footer {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url(./Group\ 4265.svg);
    }
    .header-icon{
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .margin-top-60 {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .lato-bold {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1.21;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .lato-bolder {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .font-size-21 {
        font-size: 21px;
    }
    .font-size-18 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .margin-top-20 {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .margin-top-30 {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .margin-bottom-30 {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .width-100-percent {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-around{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-between{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flex-justify-space-between{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .flex{
        display: flex;
    }
    .justify-flex-end {
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .maroon-bg {
        color:#7a2693;
    }
    .width-80-percent {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .dashed-border{
        border: 1px dashed #8b4c9e;
        width: 320px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: super;
    }
    .padding-left-right-10-percent {
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    .width-150 {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .margin-bottom-20{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .flex-column {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .footerIcons {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
    }
    .margin-left-20 {
        margin-left:20px;
    }
    .color-white{
        color: white;
    }
    /* @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .main-container {
            padding: 0;
        } 
       
    } */

  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="header-icon"><img src="./Group 4254.svg" class="width-100"></div>
        <div class="lato-bold">Package Purchase Successful!</div>
        <div class="font-size-21 margin-top-60">Hi <span class="lato-bolder" th:text="${invoiceName}"></span></div>
        <div class="font-size-18 margin-top-20">You have successfully purchased the <span class="lato-bolder" th:text="${planName}">SUPERSAVER</span> package.</div>
        <div class="font-size-18"> Package details can be found below.</div>
        <div class="margin-top-20 font-size-18 lato-bolder">Simplify Office Commute with GetToWork.</div>
        <div class="font-size-18 lato-bolder">Enjoy Stress-free work days. </div>
        <hr class="margin-top-30 width-100-percent">
        <section id="packageDetails" class="width-80-percent margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30">
            <div class="flex-justify-space-around font-size-18">
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Package Name</span>
                    <span th:text="${planName}" class="margin-top-30">SUPERSAVER</span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Rides/Validity</span>
                    <div class="margin-top-30">
                        <span th:text="${planBooking}">10 Rides/</span>
                        <span th:text="${planDays}">90 Days</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column">
                    <span class="lato-bolder maroon-bg">Cost</span>
                    <div class="margin-top-30">&#x20b9;<span th:text="${invoicePrice}">200</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="flex-justify-space-around font-size-18 margin-top-30">
                    <span th:text="${planName}">SuperSaver</span>
                    <div>
                    <span th:text="${planBooking}">10 Rides/</span>
                    <span th:text="${planDays}">90 Days</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>&#x20b9; <span th:text="${invoicePrice}">200</div>
            </div> -->

        </section>
        <hr class="width-100-percent"> 
        <section>
            <div class="margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30">
                <img src="./Shape.svg">
                <span class="dashed-border"></span>
                <img src="./Group 2224.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="margin-bottom-20 flex-justify-space-between lato-bolder">
                <span>Home</span>
                <!-- <span class="visibilty-hide"></span> -->
                <span>Office</span>
            </div>
            <div class="margin-bottom-30 flex-justify-space-between">
                <span class="width-150">Infosys Pvt Ltd, Electronic City, Bangalore </span>
                <!-- <span class="visibilty-hide"></span> -->
                <span class="width-150 justify-flex-end flex">MoveInsync , 17th Cross, HSR Laypot, Bangalore</span>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
      
    <footer>
        <div class="footerIcons">
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between">
                <a class="color-white" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/14637641/admin/">
                    <img src="./Group 3013.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/GetToWork6">
                    <img src="./Group 3012.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/Get_To_Work_MIS/">
                    <img src="./Group 3015.svg" />
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Get-To-Work-1391007324386201/">
                    <img src="./Path 611.svg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between margin-top-20">
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="color-white">Copyright © MoveinSync Technology Solutions Pvt Ltd</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-justify-space-between" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <a class="color-white" target="_blank" href="http://gettowork.io">
                    gettowork.io
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20"  href="">
                    Privacy Policy
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" href="">
                    Terms and Conditions
                </a>
                <a class="color-white margin-left-20" href="">
                    Help & FAQs
                </a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot, its a silly mistake, I did and was not able to find.Thanks for pointing it out @gael

Comment: That's all the fun of web dev . I guess you can mark my answer as the solution for future readers.